# Proving Laplace Relationship

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> $$g(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau$$
>   If we can automatically assume $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ to be Laplace transforms of $f$ and $g$, how can I show that $$G(s) =\dfrac{F(s)}{s}$$

The only conclusion I can draw from this question is that g' = f. But, I'm not sure how to apply this information to prove the Laplace equivalence as asserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** With definition
$${\cal L}(f)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}g'(t)dt$$
Now use integration by parts.

**Edit:**
Let $u=e^{−st}$ and $dv=g′(t)dt$ then apply integration by parts
\begin{align}
{\cal L}(f)
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-st}g'(t)dt\\
&= e^{−st}g(t)\Big|_0^\infty+s\int_0^\infty e^{-st}g(t)dt\\
&= s{\cal L}(g)
\end{align}
with $g(0)=0$.

Comment: I guess a more embarrassing questions is how do I integrate this. Do I use the given integral g(t)....but that would imply g'(t) is just the function without the integral right?

Comment: Let $u=e^{-st}$ and $dv=g'(t)dt$ then apply 
$$\int u\ dv=uv-\int v\ du$$

Comment: so if dv = g'(t), then vis simply g(t).

I know that g(t) is already given, but I want to make sure that g'(t) is simply f(tau) as given in the problem.

Comment: Be sure that $g'(t)=f(t)$ :) I promise.

Comment: I have completed your helpful tips. 

$my u = e^-st.......my du = -se^-st......my dv = g'(t).....and my v = g(t)......$

But after plugging into these variables, then I lose f(t). You mentioned we need g'(t) = f(t), but we never use dV in the separation by parts. How do I recover f(t) because I need to prove G(s) = F(s)/s

Comment: see the edit...